# Is it also the same how to create an export files(csv,pdf etc) between laravel and codeigniter using datatables?

Tags: php, laravel, datatables

I've done this before but it is in Codeigniter, when Im doing it again in Laravel it doesnt work? Did i missed any links(like cdn etc etc?)? If there's what is it?

This is my header

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
      <title>Laravel 5.3 File Upload with Validation example</title>
            <script type="text/javascript" src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
            <script type="text/javascript" src="/js/jquery.min.js"></script>

       <!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
            <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
            <!-- Optional theme -->
            <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css">
            <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/dataTables.bootstrap.min.css">
            <!-- <link href="https://cdn.datatables.net/buttons/1.2.3/css/buttons.dataTables.min.css" rel="stylesheet"> -->
            <link href="css/buttons.bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

            <link href="css/buttons.dataTables.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
            <link href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.13/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
            <!-- Latest compiled and minified JavaScript -->
            <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" ></script>
            <!-- Styles -->
            <script type="text/javascript" src="js/dataTable.js"></script>
    </head>
<body>
//Some codes
</body>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/custom.js"></script> 
    <!-- Datatables -->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/buttons.colVis.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/dataTables.bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src ="js/dataTables.buttons.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/buttons.bootstrap.min.js"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript" src ="js/buttons.flash.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src ="js/buttons.html5.min.js"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript" src ="js/buttons.print.min.js"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript" src ="js/jszip.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src ="js/pdfmake.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src ="js/vfs_fonts.js"></script>


</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, It is not clear what you are trying to do from the above code sample. You have just imported the assets(.css / .js files). There seems to be no code for importing and exporting CSV/PDF files.

Comment: You should really leave this as a comment instead as an answer.

Comment: CC : @davidkonrad

Comment: Sir, the codes only shows all the imported css or js.  Am i missed anything?

Comment: @Angel : May I know what you are trying to do exactly with the code above?